# Int Overflow w/ Factorial

Tags: scala, factorial

Given:

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    if(n <= 0) 1
    else       n * factorial(n - 1)
}
```

Also, since I chose an `Int`, the following, I believe, overflow behavior is possible:

```
scala> factorial(35)
res3: Int = 0
```

What's a simple example of `int` multiplication leading to an overflow equal to `0`?

Comment: Stack overflows are always a possibility.  Recursive functions that are not tail recursive are just the most common cause, because they involve many nested method calls and each method call takes up some stack space.

Comment: @puhlen Sure, but in a simple program like this, if  [Tail Call Optimization](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/tail-call-optimization-and-java/240167044) is performed it is very unlikely that you would be able to overflow the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's a simple example of int multiplication leading to an overflow equal to 0?

```
scala> -2147483648 * 2
res4: Int = 0
```

Where :

```
Int.MaxValue + 1 = -2147483648
```

For `factorial(35)` it definitely overflowed more than once on it's way there.

Comment: Thanks. But why doesn't `Int.MaxValue + 1` overflow as well, given that its multiples appear to overflow to 0?

Comment: @KevinMeredith It does. It rolls right back to a negative number.